# How to associate three tables？

Tags: oracle, join

I have three tables ABC. I hope to display all records of A while linking BC. Field a1 of A is associated with field b1 of B. a1 may be empty, so I wrote

```
A.a1=B.b1(+)
```

The two fields c and d of table C are associated with A.a2 and B.b2 respectively
so i wrote

```
A.a2 = C.c(+) and B.b2 = C.d(+)
```

The total sql is as follows

```
select A.a1, A.a2, B.e,C.f, 
from A, B, C
where A.a1=B.b1(+)
and A.a2 = C.c(+)
and B.b2 = C.d(+)
```

But the prompt says that a table can only have one external link at most.

I tried to use case when to display the information of B and C,

```
select A.a1, A.a2, 
case when a1 is null then null
else (selece B.e from B
where B.b1=A.a1) end,
case when a1 is null then null
when (selece B.e from B
where B.b1=A.a1) is null then null
else (selece C.f from C
where C.c=A.a2 and C.d=B.b2) end
from A
```

but is there any other better association method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Older" (I believe lower than 21c) Oracle database versions won't let you outer join one table to two or more other tables using the "old" Oracle's `(+)` outer join operator.

But, if you switch to `JOIN`s, then you won't have that problem. Something like this:

```
select *
from b left join a on a.a1 = b.b1
       left join c on c.d = b.b2 and c.c = a.a2
```

(Fetch columns you want, include conditions you need, but - that's the general idea.)